# Cyclomatic Complexity With Compound Conditions and Short Circuiting

Tags: unit-testing, testing, graph, graph-theory, cyclomatic-complexity

I am studying Cyclomatic Complexity in my Software Quality Assurance course at the University and I am having a hard time understanding how it works when you have compound conditions in a predicate statement or node. I have seen multiple definitions of Cyclomatic Complexity, the primary of which used my in my class is

```
V(G) = # of predicate nodes (with outdegree = 2) + 1
```

So for a program graph such as this we would have a cyclomatic complexity of two:

```
V(G) = 2
```

[image: Program graph with cyclomatic complexity of two]

I have also seen definitions of the Cyclomatic complexity given as

```
V(G) = # edges - # nodes + 2
```

Which also works for the graph given above. However, we we have compound conditions for predicate nodes. And we consider a language and system set up for automatic short circuiting, it seems to me the graph on the below to the left would have to be expanded to the graph. **If this is the case such as below, does the Cyclomatic complexity become 3, even if in the real source code, we may only have a single if statement or is it still V(G) = 2?**.

It is confusing because most of the definitions I see of Cyclomatic complexity are talking about predicate nodes, and as I understand predicates they may contain multiple short-circuited conditions. If this not the case, it seems that short-circuiting behavior, while giving performance increases, actually raises Cyclomatic complexity when considered. **If source code is given, must all the conditions be broken into their own nodes such as the graph on the left before we can calculate cyclomatic complexity?**
[image: Program graph expanded to show short circuiting behavior]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C (C++, Java, C#) the "&&" operator adds one to complexity because it's defined to use short-circuit evaluation. Cyclomatic Complexity in this case would be 3.

See http://hissa.nist.gov/HHRFdata/Artifacts/ITLdoc/235/chapter4.htm

"Boolean operators add either one or nothing to complexity, depending on whether they have short-circuit evaluation semantics that can lead to conditional execution of side-effects."

Figure 4-4 has annotated source code and a corresponding flow graph that demonstrate how complexity is determined.

See also [Cyclomatic complexity of IF((A>B) AND (C>D)) and IF((A>B) OR (C>D))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599942/cyclomatic-complexity-of-ifab-and-cd-and-ifab-or-cd)