# How is cyclomatic complexity counted?

Tags: testing, tdd, complexity-theory, metrics, cyclomatic-complexity

I'm reading Kent Beck's “TDD by Example” and I can't understand why the cyclomatic complexity of his program is fractional.

[image: Table from the book]

[In Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity?oldformat=true) the complexity is defined as `M = E − N + 2P` where E, N and P are integers.

Comment: There are four definitions of CC. :-) Take a look here if you need example with drawings and calculations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599942/cyclomatic-complexity-of-ifab-and-cd-and-ifab-or-cd/21658235#21658235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that's the average of each method's standalone cyclomatic complexity (`M = E - N + 2`). I'm not going to calculate it myself, but

- most of the methods shown have no conditionals by that point in the exercise (Kent eliminates them when he can), so their cyclomatic complexity is 1
- `Bank.rate` does have a single `if` (page 63)

so it seems reasonable that the average is just above 1.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. Thank you :)