# Calculating Cyclomatic Complexity

Tags: cyclomatic-complexity

So I'm trying to understand cyclomatic complexity. If I have a line of code that looks like a = b && c where a, b, and c are bool. For this statement would the complexity be 1 or would it be more like doing if statements since you have to check b and c? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21658235/999165

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Cyclomatic Complexity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911637/what-is-cyclomatic-complexity)